# What exactly network implementation has been used in Blockchains?

Tags: blockchain, p2p

I'm already working on a blockchain project, However I have a problem on implementing a peer to peer network between nodes. I found a Udemy course and in that course Redis pub/sub was used for peet to peer network but is it only available in a local network right ? or in another article it says that there are some main nodes that run 24/7 so others first make connection with them. but is it not sort of server-side network ??
my question is how can I actually implement a peer to peer network that many nodes around the world can communicate with each other without any main server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usual implementation of P2P connection is to have one predefined port (for example in case of Bitcoin Core it's [8333](https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node#network-configuration)) and the applications periodically broadcast their messages on this particular port.

It's also usual to have in your app a preset list of nodes that are likely to be online 24/7, so that the app can listen to their messages right from the startup and doesn't have to wait for other nodes to broadcast their presence.

The app can keep a list of currently active nodes (for example the ping period is 60 seconds, so any node that has pinged within the last 60 seconds is considered active) in case it needs to communicate with the other nodes directly.

But most communication is usually done via broadcasting and listening to messages on the predefined port.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. so as I realized if the predefined port goes down ( or other main active nodes ). the whole system goes down and blockchain verification doesn't work anymore right ?

Comment: How would the port go down? It's just a parameter of the communication protocol.... As long as you have few nodes that are able to communicate on the (P2P) network on the specified port, you have a functioning P2P network between them. But if a computer is not able to communicate on the port (and there are no backup ways such as a secondary port in the network definition), it would not be able to connect and use the network.

Comment: alright I think I get it. so what about IP addresses ? did we need some nodes with static IP addresses 24/7 online ? like a server ? and in other nodes we have list of that main nodes that their IP addresses never changes ?

Comment: The static IPs are not needed - your app can always wait for other nodes to broadcast their presence. But if you want to be able to connect to other nodes quickly, they should have a static IP that IP should be defined in the app so it knows where to connect on startup.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation